# Converting strings to DATE in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, date

i have an old database that I'm converting from Access to MS SQL Server 2008. In the Access database, dates were written as 02/2008 so MM/YYYY. I want to convert this to a DATE type, where I can show something like MM/DD/YYYY. Is there any way to do that using SQL Server? When I tried CONVERT, it fails beacuse there are some irregular dates, such a

- 1/2008
- 01/2004
- /2001
- /4
- etc

so my thought is that I will just write up some code to go through each date and use regex to convert it, and then save it back to the database in a new table.

Any thoughts on how to make this easier?

Comment: Were the dates in the Access database strings or some other more useful data type?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your only choice here is some sort of string manipulation like you've proposed.  What part of the process would you like to make easier?

Comment: I thought there may be something I'm over looking. I was hoping to just write up a script in SQL instead of writing in C# and then pushing the data back to the database.

Comment: You may be able to manipulate the string in the SQL, although SQL Server is generally clumsy when it comes to string manipulation.  There are also ways to access the .NET CLI from SQL, which would give you access to better string manipulation methods.  Start http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254498.aspx.